# Como usar variável membro da struct para pré definir tamanho de matriz

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como pre definir o tamanho de uma matriz dentro de uma struct da forma:

```
struct exemplo{
  int l;
  int c;
  int matriz[l][c];
};
```

o compilador reclama que l e c na linha da matriz não está declarada aqui.

Comment: Apenas com uso de memoria dinamica `int **matriz`

Comment: Assim como o @FábioMorais indicou, da forma que está escrito só dinamicamente, mas se tanto `l` como `c` forem constantes, através de um `#define` por exemplo já irá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Quando se trabalha com vetor, tem que se ter em mente que existem dois tipos: vetores estáticos e vetores dinâmicos. O vetor da sua struct no caso é um vetor estático, você pode até declarar ele e usar (se seu código e lógica estiverem correto, claro), mas o tamanho desse vetor deve ser declarado por você, programador. E como fazer isso? Com comandos de pré-processamento #define:

```
#define j 10
```

agora, quando posso usar j para declarar um vetor estático, porém, o usuário não irá interferer em nenhum momento, afinal, são comandos de PRÉ-processamento. Recomendo isso caso seja isso que você queira fazer.

Caso você queira uma intervenção do usuário sobre o tamanho do vetor, você vai precisar de um vetor dinâmico:

```
char *vetor = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

Caso queira saber mais sobre alocação dinâmica, recomendo acessar esse [link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html).